# How to use d3.scale.linear to color a map in d3

Tags: d3.js

The following code is from d3 book/Interactive Data Visualization for the Web Book-Scott Murray
Chapter  14/ 05_choropleth.html
This choropleth uses US agriculture productivity data. I needed a very similar-looking map for some sales data for different states. So, I tried to replace the data with mine. My data has a similar structure, states in one column and the total amount of sales for those states in the other column(I think it is not possible to attach my csv here? I'm just attaching a screenshot of some of it to give an idea) [image: highest values in the dataset])

The problem is that the coloring method that’s used in the sample, d3.scaleQuantize(), didn’t give good results with my data. Despite the big differences in the amounts between different states, it colors many of them the same. I heard that d3.scaleQuantize() is better to use with small numbers whereas my data has big values such as hundreds of millions. Can this be the reason for the problem? I attached how my map looks like. For instance, California has twice the value of its closest follower but the map colors it the same with many others.

Not sure if this will be the solution but I tried to use d3.scale.linear() however couldn’t make it work. I am very new to this. I am using Webstorm to edit the code. If you think using d3.scale.linear() for the coloring will work for me, I‘ll appreciate any helps with how to edit the code.

[![how my map looks like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3: Setting path fills dynamically to generate a choropleth</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
   /* No style rules here yet */  
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   //Width and height
   var w = 500;
   var h = 300;

   //Define map projection
   var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
           .translate([w/2, h/2])
           .scale([500]);

   //Define path generator
   var path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection);
        
   //Define quantize scale to sort data values into buckets of color
   var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
        .range(["rgb(237,248,233)","rgb(186,228,179)","rgb(116,196,118)","rgb(49,163,84)","rgb(0,109,44)"]);
        //Colors derived from ColorBrewer, by Cynthia Brewer, and included in
        //https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic

   //Create SVG element
   var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

   //Load in agriculture data
   d3.csv("us-sales-by-state.csv", function(data) {

    //Set input domain for color scale
    color.domain([
     d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }),
     d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })
    ]);

    //Load in GeoJSON data
    d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {

     //Merge the ag. data and GeoJSON
     //Loop through once for each ag. data value
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    
      //Grab state name
      var dataState = data[i].state;
      
      //Grab data value, and convert from string to float
      var dataValue = parseFloat(data[i].value);
    
      //Find the corresponding state inside the GeoJSON
      for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {
      
       var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.name;
    
       if (dataState == jsonState) {
      
        //Copy the data value into the JSON
        json.features[j].properties.value = dataValue;
        
        //Stop looking through the JSON
        break;
        
       }
      }  
     }

     //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
     svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          //Get data value
          var value = d.properties.value;
          
          if (value) {
           //If value exists…
           return color(value);
          } else {
           //If value is undefined…
           return "#ccc";
          }
        });
   
    });
   
   });
   
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5oxX.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5oxX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a linear color scale as follow:

```
const myColor = d3.scale.linear()
                   .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }))
                   .range(["red", "green"])
```

We are creating a linear scale scale here and mapping the lowest value to red color and highest value to green color. Below is the code where you will use the myColor

```
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(json.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    //Get data value
    var value = d.properties.value;
    if (value) {
      //If value exists…
      return myColor(value);
    } else {
      //If value is undefined…
      return "#ccc";
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Prince. I did the edits as you pointed out however it just gives me a blank screen when I run it .

Comment: Can you please create a working jsfiddle of your issue, it would be easy to apply my code on top of it.